# I need to authenticate when installing or removing software

Tags: updates, system-installation, password

I'm having trouble to install updates, because it pop-up a window requiring to authenticate. and the problem is, I don't know it.

Thanks!

Comment: Same password as you use to login assuming that you have admin rights. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Usage

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem but I do not have any password when I login. What am I supposed to enter? Regards,
Narssimhan

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer below if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question is hard to understand otherwise than that installing or removing an app is asking you to enter your login password. See, Ubuntu requires you to give permission for every action or task involving changes to your system, so simply use your login pass-phrase when installing or removing an app.

Comment: Hi! You know I tried putting my login password but it still doesn't work..

Comment: then please explain what exactly is happening, its hard to help without enough info. Does this happens in usc or cli?

Comment: Hey, danijelic? I tried again what u said and finally it worked! thanks a lot! I guess I must have misspelled something